# electric potentials of charged concentric shells after earthing

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electricity, potential

> Two concentric shells have radii $R$ and $2R$, charge $q_1$ and $q_2$, and potentials $3V$ and $V$, respectively. Now, the outer shell is earthed. What will their final potentials be?

I have always had trouble solving such questions. My attempt was to assume that the charge changes from $q_1$ to $q$ and distribute charges according to Gauss's law but the problem was that I had two variables and 1 equation.

How do I proceed? A hint would be enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Gauss's law to find the field everywhere, remembering that the field is zero inside of a conductor
2. Integrate the field everywhere to find the potential.  You will have an integration constant in each piecewise region of space
3. Use the fact that the potential has to be continuous, plus the grounding condition, to fix the integration constant.

Comment: Please elaborate a little

Comment: @LakshyaGupta -- there's not much elaboration I can do without explicitly solving the problem.  This is a pretty standard homework problem, and we're not a homework site.

Comment: Is there another method?

Answer (score 0):

I assume they mean potential difference since they havent mentioned any particular point.The potential at any point is the sum of the potential due to individual charges.When you ground one sphere you fix the potential of that sphere to Zero.(Since all potentials are relative to ground)The potential difference is now potential of ungrounded sphere minus potential of grounded sphere(zero).